# Add Tailwind CSS to elements in the DOM

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I need to apply Tailwind CSS styles to a specific part of DOM.

```html
<body>
  <div class="part1">
     <h2 class="font-bold">This is part1 of the application.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="part2">
     ...part2
  </div>
</body>
```

For example, I need to apply styles to `part1` of the application. So, the applied styles would be something like this:

```css
.part1 h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Is there any way to apply styles such as the above example? I'm using Tailwind in my React app.

Comment: If you're using Tailwind inside a React application, you need to be using `className` instead of `class`.

Comment: I know. It's just an HTML example regardless of any framework.

Comment: FYI, the `font-bold` that you are adding to your `<h2>` is the same as applying `font-weight: 700`. As one of the answers says, adding utility classes directly to your HTML elements like this is best way to use Tailwind, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on Tailwind's utility classes as much as possible to style your elements, Tailwind is built around the concept of utility classes to help you style your project according to your needs.

If after careful consideration you still find that you need to add custom styles, you have a couple of options.

- Use Arbitrary values:

```
<div>
  <h2 className="font-[700]">This is part1 of the application.</h2>
</div>
```

- Add a custom style inside the main css file of your project. Like this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.your-custom-style {
  /* ... */
}
```

- Use the `@layer` directive to add the custom style inside one of Tailwind's layers. For example if you were to add your custom style inside the `utilities` layer, it would look something like this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .your-custom-style {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

See [Arbitrary Values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values) for details.

See [Adding Custom Styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using the tailwind classes in `index.css` like:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  .part1 h2 {
    @apply font-bold; // which compiles to font-weight : 700;
  }
}
```

For custom weight use

```
.part1 h2 {
    @apply font-[700]; // Here 700 is custom font-weight
 }
```

**Note** : When font-weight is applied both in `index.css` and in React component's class using `className` , property of `index.css` is considered.

For Example:

index.css

```
.part1 h2 {
    @apply font-[400]; // Here 700 is custom font-weight
 }
```

React component

```
  <body>
    <div class="part1">
      <h2 class="font-[800]">This is part1 of the application.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="part2">...part2</div>
  </body>
```

Output - font-weight:400 is applied

[image]